# Github workflow says only run on pull_request. Why does it run when code is pushed?

Tags: github-actions

I have a very simple Github workflow as below:

```
name: CI
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  ci:
  ...
```

I though that this means that the workflow will only run on a pull request to "main". However it runs whenever I push the code to Github, even when I push it to the "feature1" branch.

Am I not understanding something basic? Should this be happening? Do I need something else in the workflow file? Or do I perhaps have a repo setting that is misconfigured?

Comment: I suspect there is some error in your setup.  [here](https://github.com/2e0byo/test-pr) is a basic gh repo I just created with a workflow which runs only on pr (tested).

Comment: Is there a PR open from the `feature1` branch when you see it building? `pull_request` is, implicitly, on types `opened`, `synchronize`, and `reopened`, where `synchronize` is triggered when you push a new commit into a PR.

Comment: @BenjaminW. You're exactly right! I had a PR open from the feature1 branch. I didn't realize that Github was smart enough to modify a PR in progress and re-run checks when new code is pushed to the source branch. When I closed out that PR and push more code, the workflow did not run again.